# Is there a way to hide all panels in visual studio (not full screen mode)?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I know there is a way to have Visual Studio in full screen : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But in this configuration, you cannot set the editor as a normal window, to move it for an example and to use other applications in the same time.

Is there another way to have the window in configuration that i want ?

Comment: Drag the document window out of the IDE window and it becomes a standalone window. The main window can then be minimised. You can even drag multiple documents into the new window and still use all the tab layout options.

Comment: Very cool. It was exactly what I searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the document window out of the IDE window and it becomes a standalone window.

The main window can then be minimised.

You can even drag multiple documents into the new window and still use all the tab layout options are available in such secondary windows (including tool window docking, eg. a second solution explorer window)..